# Compensation for saving large sums of money

Tags: compensation

I am on the brink of saving my current employer approximately $2 million per year is it appropriate to ask for some type of monetary compensation beyond my salary?

Comment: did you lead this initiative, or are you being managed by someone, and the idea to save 2mill a year came from someone else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: "I am on the brink..."  Maybe you should wait until you have actually done it before asking for a reward.

Comment: What's the context of this savings? $2M to a company with a $10B budget might not be as big a deal as $2M to a company with a $5M budget.

Comment: are you going to pay them for any mistakes you make?

Comment: That really depends. What is your role at this company? Were you tasked with finding savings? Or was/is this on your own initiative? What is the context?

Answer (score 6):

> I am on the brink of saving my current employer approximately $2
>   million per year is it appropriate to ask for some type of monetary
>   compensation beyond my salary?

**Yes**, it definitely is.

The company doesn't *have too*, but most good companies will offer up a significant bonus for this type of year to year savings.

The only other thing I would add is to make double sure you can back up the savings you are claiming.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I would watch on how and when to bring the issue to them depending on your rank inside the company.

As like:

- Some companies do annual meeting with each boss to quantify the bonus they can have.
- Some companies do performance review of each team members for salary gain and bonus.

Keep in mind it can be harder to justify if you are inside a union, as often bonus or salary are standardized, but in such case you might receive a honorary reward.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a good position to ask, so if you feel comfortable doing so, why not.  I would not go into it expecting it.  As Tina_sea alluded in comments, companies also take on the risks an employee brings.  In return employees get relative stability.

The bigger questions surround your uniqueness vs. your simply being in the right place.  Were you and you alone the key factor in this major savings or were you just the current cog in the machine assigned to fulfill it.  Can the skills you leveraged to achieve this be replaced with reasonable effort or was this your brainchild that virtually no one else could have conceived much less created?  Is there any reason to believe keeping you happy will lead you to the next $2M annual savings or was this an isolated incident?

Either way, asking rarely hurts once you've delivered value.  Just make sure you ask knowing how replaceable your role in that savings was.